# Depth first search using node gives, RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I’m trying to rewrite my code to get over a stack size error “RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded” I run into. I’m trying to run a DFS using a stack in JavaScript using node.

I’ve heard a lot about settimeout but I’m not sure how to implement it in my case. Any advice would be great.

Heres the code that fails:

```
var Stack = function() {
    this.items = [];
};
Stack.prototype.push = function(obj) {
    this.items.push(obj);
};
Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
    return this.items.pop();
};
Stack.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.items.length === 0;
};
Stack.prototype.isExplored = function(n){
    return this.items.indexOf(n) !== -1;
}
Stack.prototype.emptyOut = function() {
    this.items = [];
    return this.items.length === 0;

};

var stack = new Stack();
var adjList=[];
for(var i= 1; i<15557;i++){
    adjList.push([i])
}   
adjList.push([0])

function DFS(graph, s){
    stack.push(s);
    for(var i = 0 ; i < graph[s].length; i++){
        var v = graph[s][i];
        if(!stack.isExplored(v)){           
            DFS(graph, v);  
        }                       
    }   
}
DFS(adjList, 0) 
console.log("done", stack);
```

Comment: I have no idea what it is supposed to do but you call `DFS` recursively 15557 times, which is too much for the stack to handle.

Comment: I agree but what if my dataset has over 15557 nodes. I was wondering if setTimeout can solve the problem or if you know of some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered switching to an iterative approach?

```js
var Stack = function() {
  this.items = [];
};
Stack.prototype.push = function(obj) {
  this.items.push(obj);
};
Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
  return this.items.pop();
};
Stack.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  return this.items.length === 0;
};
Stack.prototype.isExplored = function(n) {
  return this.items.indexOf(n) !== -1;
}
Stack.prototype.emptyOut = function() {
  this.items = [];
  return this.items.length === 0;
};

var stack = new Stack();
var adjList = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 15557; i++) {
  adjList.push([i]);
}
adjList.push([0])

function DFS(graph, v) {
  var queue = [v];
  while (queue.length) {
    v = queue.pop();
    if (stack.isExplored(v))
      continue;
    stack.push(v);
    for (var i = graph[v].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      queue.push(graph[v][i]);
    }
  }
}
DFS(adjList, 0);
console.log("done", stack);
```

The limit is now the amount of memory node has at disposal.